# Java Lanterna - how can I get input from a textbox?

Tags: java, string, user-interface, textbox, lanterna

I'm a relatively new Java programmer (about two months experience) and I can't figure out how to get the data inputted into a [Lanterna](https://code.google.com/p/lanterna/) (a library for creating terminal user interfaces) textbox into a string for later use.

Here is my code:

```
//Variables (that I can't seem to populate)
final String usernameIn = null;
final String passwordIn = null;

//Username panel, contains Label and TextBox
Panel username = new Panel(new Border.Invisible(), Panel.Orientation.HORISONTAL);
username.addComponent(new Label("Username: "));
username.addComponent(new TextBox(null, 15));
addComponent(username);

//Password panel, contains label and PasswordBox
Panel password = new Panel(new Border.Invisible(), Panel.Orientation.HORISONTAL);
password.addComponent(new Label("Password: "));
password.addComponent(new PasswordBox(null, 15));
addComponent(password);

//Controls panel, contains Button w/ action
Panel controls = new Panel(new Border.Invisible(), Panel.Orientation.HORISONTAL);
controls.addComponent(new Button("Login", new Action()
{
    public void doAction() {
        MessageBox.showMessageBox(getOwner(), "Alert", "You entered the username " + usernameIn + " and password " + passwordIn + ".");
    }
}));
addComponent(controls);
```

Any help would be really appreciated. I have looked all over for information but there really isn't much on [Lanterna](https://code.google.com/p/lanterna/) and it's the only up-to-date Java library that I could find allowing me to make terminal applications. *Please note: I'm aware there's nothing in the above code that'll process the inputted data, I left out all of my attempts as they caused pages upon pages of errors (which is to be expected when using the wrong functions).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a look into the  Lanterna code: `TextBox` has a `getText()` method.

As an idea:

```
Panel username = new Panel(new Border.Invisible(), Panel.Orientation.HORISONTAL);
username.addComponent(new Label("Username: "));
TextBox userBox = new TextBox(null, 15);
username.addComponent(userBox);
addComponent(username);
// ... and later elsewhere 
usernameIn = userBox.getText();
```

Shure, you need a reference to userBox to get the content later elsewhere in your code.

Lanterna has also a ComponentListener interface to response if a value changed:

```
Panel username = new Panel(new Border.Invisible(), Panel.Orientation.HORISONTAL);
username.addComponent(new Label("Username: "));
TextBox userBox = new TextBox(null, 15);
userBox.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
    void onComponentValueChanged(InteractableComponent component) {
         usernameIn = ((TextBox)component).getText();
    }
});

username.addComponent(userBox);
addComponent(username);
```

That seems even cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

There are no `addComponent()` method in `TextBox` class, **`Lanterna ver3.0.0-beta2`.**
So use `readInput()` in `Screen`. 
Below sample represent when user press enter, get text from TextBox.

```
private Screen screen;
private TextBox textBox; 
private final String emptyString = "";
...
public String getText() throws IOException {
    String result = null;
    KeyStroke key = null;
    while ((key = screen.readInput()).getKeyType() != KeyType.Enter) {
        textBox.handleKeyStroke(key);
       // use only one of handleInput() or handleKeyStroke() 
        textBox.setText(textBox.getText()); 
    }
    result = textBox.getText();
    textBox.setText(emptyString);
    return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to extend `TextBox` and override `handleKeyStroke` such that the `TextBox` itself initiates whatever action you wish to occur once the user hits `Enter`. This is useful if the flow of your program would make it inconvenient or impossible to manually handle inputs in your main thread. For example, this could be used create a reusable `TextBox` in your UI:

```
public class ReusableTextBox extends TextBox {
    //instance variables
    ...

    //constructors
    ...

    @Override
    public Result handleKeyStroke(KeyStroke keyStroke) {
        if (keyStroke.getKeyType() == KeyType.Enter){
            String userInput = getText();
            setText("");
            takeFocus();
            
            //do stuff with userInput and instance variables

            return Result.HANDLED;
        }
        return super.handleKeyStroke(keyStroke);
    }
}
```

The main downside to this approach is that you would have to implement all the necessary calls to the `TextBox` constructors yourself:

```
public ReusableTextBox(/*vals for instance variables,*/
                       String initialContent, TerminalSize preferredSize, Style style){
    super(initialContent, preferredSize, style);
    //init instance variables
}

//and so on for the multiple constructors that take
//various combinations of a String, TerminalSize, or Style
```

This is somewhat tedious, but you can probably limit yourself to just implementing the constructors you'll actually use.